# Invalid redirect_uri with 'omniauth-facebook' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, rubygems, omniauth

So I went to this [guide](http://bit.ly/qStKqp) that explains how to start with omniauth. When I got to the end of step 4 to test the application at localhost:3000/auth/facebook, I got this error:

```
{ 
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 191
    }
}
```

I understand the problem is the URL in the Facebook developer center, but none of the solutions I read works for me...

(I know that there are some questions before regarding this issue, but I'm new to Ruby on Rails and need an explanation for dummies.)

Answer (score 23):

Defining these settings at the [Facebook developer center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) solved this for me:

- App Domain: (blank)
- Site URL: `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 2):

Check the website option and set the site URL to `http://localhost:3000/`.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes i did try this but when i do i get this error  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Answer (score 2):

If the Facebook user is being generated in your Ruby on Rails application as

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook
```

you need configure the Facebook application (Website) under the App section to redirect to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a production environment, something that i missed was just removing www. from the site url that you specify in the facebook app settings (settings > basic > Website with Facebook Login > site url).

so instead of http://www.website.com/ you should enter in http://website.com

this worked for me after a few hours of trying to figure out what was wrong and why i was getting this redirect erro.

Answer (score 0):

If you already added a site url you must provide email and turn your app live, you can add email in settings -> basic -> contact email and then make your app live in APP REVIEW -> MAKE "you_app_name" PUBLIC? -> yes